# What's the idiomatic way to keep track of previous values in clojure?

Tags: clojure

```
(defmethod learn [:SARSA :Module] [learner module] 
  (let [samples (get learner :dataset)]  
    (for [seq samples]
      (let [laststate (atom 0) lastaction (atom 0) lastreward (atom 0)])
       ;;Do some stuff
       ;;Update laststate,lastaction,lastreward

      )

    ))
```

Im using a for loop to iterate through a sequence but perhaps I should use a regular loop and recur? Would a map/reduce be useful here?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Be careful -- in Clojure, it's better to think of `for` not as a loop, but as a list comprehension -- it takes a collection and returns a modified/filtered version of that collection.

You can do this more idiomatically (in a more functional programming style) by using loop and recur, something like this:

```
(defmethod learn [:SARSA Module] [learner module]
  (loop [samples (get learner :dataset)
         last-state 0
         last-action 0
         last-reward 0]
    (if-let [sample (first samples)]
      (recur (next samples) (new-last-state) (new-last-action) (new-last-reward))
      [last-state last-action last-reward])))
```

Each time you iterate through with new values for `last-state`, `last-action` and `last-reward`, the `(if-let [sample (first samples)]` part determines whether there are any samples left to look at -- if there aren't, that means you're at the end of the list, and `(first '())` will return `nil`, so your results will be returned in whatever form you'd like -- see the last line, where I just returned them as a vector. If there are still samples left, we bind the first one to the symbol `sample`, which you can use for your updated calculations of `last-state`, etc., then `recur` with these updated values and `(next samples)`, which is everything after the first sample in that list.

EDIT: I would generally try and do things using map/reduce whenever I can, but whenever you are trying to do a complicated looping operation where you're tallying and calculating a handful of different statistics, loop/recur is usually the best way to go.

Comment: `loop-recur` is primarily the low-level mechanism used to implement higher-level primitives. Its usage in client code is almost never motivated by expressiveness or readability. The primary motivator is performance, but only rarely is it a justified optimization.

Comment: My point is that sometimes, if you're dealing with a complicated loop and more than a few local variables, it ends up being easier/simpler to just use loop/recur. Granted, in this case after reading @omiel's solution, I think I'm wrong -- reduce is a good deal simpler in this case.

Answer (score 5):

@DaveYarwood alluded to `map`/`reduce` in his answer ; here's how you could implement it:

```clj
(defmethod learn [:SARSA Module] [learner module]
  (reduce (fn [[state action reward] sample]
            ;; do some stuff and computes new values for state/action/reward
            [new-state new-action new-reward])
          [0 0 0]
          (get learner :dataset)))
```

Comment: If I could click two solutions I would. Great solution as well. Thanks.